# Norm exercises in Linear system theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know question like "Help me answer this list" are not welcome at this forum. However, I struggle with some basics on matrix theory and do not know how to start answering some exercises. Therefore, I beg your mercy for helping me answer these questions below.

[image]

I know what a matrix and a norm is. But when comes to prove some statements, one may need some additional knowledge I lack. For example, How do I start exercise 1.6 And 1.8?

In case you are willing to help me, I ask you to say which exercise you refer to. The referred book is `Linear System theory`, Wilson J. Rugh.

Remark: Equation 10 on Exercise 1.6 is $\lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert = \max_\limits{\lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert = 1} \lvert\lvert A x \rvert\rvert$

I am aware, this question may be closed.

Comment: Without some work of your own, nobody knows where to start. Maybe you don't know what a matrix is or a norm is, how can we know?

Comment: I know what a matrix and a norm is. But when comes to prove some statements, one may need some additional knowledge I lack. For example, How do I start exercise 1.6 And 1.8?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto For exercise 1.6, we at least need to know what "the definition in (10)" is referring to

Comment: I added a remark.